# Unable to position an element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position this 'ABOUT ME' box but I am unable to posiition it down. I can move it left or right using margin-left or margin-right properties but I'm not able to move it top or down. I have used float:right to position the sidebar. So I used clear:both on my header. But still it remains stationary.

The following images will help you to understand my problem.

[image]

The code of this page is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFzp7/) (jsFiddle)

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style123.css">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    
    <title>My First Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="box">
            <h3> ABOUT ME </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background: #091A1B;
   color: #544738;
   font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#nav {
      margin-top: 0px;
      float: right;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em; 
}

li a {
    color: #544738;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 12px;
}

li a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
    color: #25296F;
}

#box {
      background-color: black;
      width: 150px;
      height: 38px;
      margin-left: 500px;
      clear: both;
      margin-top: 500px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #box {
position:absolute;

background-color: black;

width: 150px;

height: 38px;

margin-left: 0px;

clear: both;

margin-top: 200px;
```

}

Take a look at this demo:
give different position to margin-top and the position changes....

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/ZFzp7/1/

Comment: Yeah.. For sure.. Actually u missed the css property 
position :absolute;
Postion:absolute takes the position from its parent div.. so u can arrange the div anywhere of its parent div's height...

Answer (score 0):

Used to this code

```
#box:before, #wrapper:before{
    content:"";
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    display:table;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/ZFzp7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is a **vertical margin collapse**.
To prevent it add the following rule targeting your wrapper div
That will do. No need of other changes

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/T2CBr/)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is the floating elements, i guess. To make your top margin work, just insert an empty div with style [clear:both] as shown below,
`

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      <div style='clear:both'></div>
        <div id="box">
            <h3> ABOUT ME </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>`
```